# Oracle not using index, Entity Framework & Devart DotConnect for oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, devart

The table in question has ~30mio records. Using Entity Framework I write a LINQ Query like this:

```
dbContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Col3 == "BQJCRHHNABKAKU-KBQPJGBKSA-N");
```

Devart DotConnect for Oracle generates this:

```
SELECT
Extent1.COL1,
Extent1.COL2,
Extent1.COL3
FROM MY_TABLE Extent1
WHERE (Extent1.COL3 = :p__linq__0) OR ((Extent1.COL3 IS NULL) AND (:p__linq__0 IS NULL))
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

The query takes about four minutes, obviously a full table scan.

However, handcrafting this SQL:

```
SELECT
Extent1.COL1,
Extent1.COL2,
Extent1.COL3
FROM MY_TABLE Extent1
WHERE Extent1.COL3 = :p__linq__0
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

returns the expected match in 200ms.

Question: Why is it so? I would expect the query optimizer to note that the right part is false if the parameter is not null, so why doesn't the first query hit the index?

Comment: can you show the explain plan?

Comment: well, sort of. The problem happened in production, where this actual table is a public synonym to another schema. For development I am creating the table in a containerized DB. So I am unsure if this would help. Maybe I can get the DBA guys to share the real plan

Answer (score 0):

Please set [UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior=false](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?QueryOptions.html) explicitly:

```
  var config = Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.Configuration.OracleEntityProviderConfig.Instance;
  config.QueryOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = false;
```

If this doesn't help, [send us](https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) a small test project with the corresponding DDL script so that we can investigate the issue.